# Sync wireless network information to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wireless-networking

Is it possible to sync the wireless network information to your iPhone from a computer (MacBook Pro in my case). Our wireless at work has a REALLY long and complicated password, and I've already typed it in on my computer, and if I could sync that it would be nice, instead of typing it out on my iPhone keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any functionality like that but if you email the password to yourself and use copy and paste on the iPhone it would be a pretty easy task.

Comment: As a guy in my office pointed out, this is the best bet, since you can get the password from the keychain utility. Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) to create a profile for the device which contains your wireless password. The utility will allow you to load that profile onto the phone.

(The profile can configure all types of other settings as well.)